# One LinearLayoutManager is only for one RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I am building an app having three RecyclerView in one fragment to show horizontal list of items. i created a LinearLayoutManager object and set it to all three RecyclerView . but it crashes app, saying one LinearLayoutManager can attached to only one RecyclerView .why can't i attach to all although i need the same Properties.
code is ..

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recViewTopSell.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recViewBrands.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recViewCategory.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

error at

```
 recViewBrands.setLayoutManager(llm);
            recViewCategory.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Comment: You can not attach the same layout manager to multiple recycler views.

Comment: why ? that i am asking why cant i attach. it is just an object with properties and i want the same properties object for other RecyclerView. so why i have to make other objects

Answer (score 0):

No it can't be reused like that.
The `LayoutManager`, `LinearLayoutManager` in your case, contains state specific to RecyclerView it is used with.

If there is a lot of setup involved for the three different LayoutMangers, consider a `createLayoutManager()` method to call three times instead.

Comment: how to use createLayoutManager()

Comment: That would be your own method creating and setting up a new instance of a LinearLayoutManager

Answer (score -1):

Following Mattias answer do this:

```
    recViewTopSell.setLayoutManager(newLLM());
    recViewBrands.setLayoutManager(newLLM());
    recViewCategory.setLayoutManager(newLLM());
```

and then:

```
    private LinearLayoutManager newLLM() {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        return linearLayoutManager;
    }
```

Comment: i know this can be done but why do i instantiate three objects of LinearLayoutManager .

Comment: Because it is given access to Recycler instance when recycling old views